# Force stereo instead of quadrophonic in speaker setup

Tags: windows-8.1, audio, speakers, asio

I use Akai EIE audio interface with ASIO drivers. EIE has 2 stereo outputs, but I regularly use only one of them (I only use the other one when I connect hardware DJ mixers). However, the Windows speaker setup window seems to think that I have quadrophonic speaker setup, which is the only option. In all 3d games, for example, sounds that are supposed to be behind player character completely disappear from the mix.

How can I force Windows to use only the first output as stereo?

Comment: How is it configured in control pannel Sound , in the playback tab when you select the "speakers" or the specific output, then (without going any deeper) selecting "configure"  bottom left?  I am not understanding completely what you mean by "only the first output" when it was not described very well how it would need to be different at other times?  It is possible to use the sound cards software settings and create a "profile" to switch to, and apply "speaker fill" for different methods.  While speaker fill is not ever perfect (can have delays) it does maintain stereo.

Comment: It is configured to use quadrophonic sound using two stereo outputs — which is the problem. By "only the first output" I mean that I actually want Windows to use only the first stereo output for all system sounds and DirectX. "how it would need to be different at other times?" — it wouldn't, I use a separate OS X machine for music work, where I need the second output. "It is possible" — how?

Comment: I think i understand, 2 outputs but only stereo need, that can be a real problem, here i have solved it one time by just Y-adapting a single output, and leaving things stereo, this worked well for 2 cheap speaker sets that were not "surround sound" but just 2 speaker sets. Everything else posed some sort of issues as you already described with even simple TV programs trying to put thier surround stuff on the other speakers/output.  Speaker fill can solve it for some things, Programs (like MCP) could use thier own configurable audio mixer. Y adapting was certannly easier and done in one.

Comment: There can also be "line out" available , which on this digital stuff is much the same levels, it is supposed to be the blue jack (and is software configured in the provided extra software).  this worked out very well with soundblaster/creative stuff, but i do not think i got very far using that with realtek.